# React Native PushNotificationIOS: CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, react-native

I am developing a react native app for both ios and android platforms. Now I want to get push notifications using [react-native-push-notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification). I am done with android case (thus I am getting token successfully). Then I decided to do the same for ios platform. I was following [this RN tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#pushnotificationios). After copy-pasting all the boilerplate I began to get this error in logs:

```
CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null)
```

I am total beginner in iOS development so I am feeling little lost while looking on this error.

Does anybody know what is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I just forgot to turn on notifications in Capabilities section of my app.